# Always vertical align DIV inside DIV

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <div class="imageBox">
       <div class="imageActions">
         <a href="#"><div class="box">link1</div></a>
       </div>
     </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="imageBox">
      <div class="imageActions">
        <a href="#"><div class="box">link1</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="box">link2</div></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
li { width : 200px; }

.imageBox { 
    with:196px; 
    height:100px; 
    position:relative; 
    background:#000; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin-bottom:2px; 
}

.imageBox .box {  
    margin: 5px auto; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border:solid 1px #6f94e1; 
    background-color:#456fd3; 
    color:#FFF; 
    width:100px; 
    font-size:13px; 
    text-align:center; 
 } 


.imageBox .imageActions { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    display: none
  }

.imageBox:hover .imageActions { display: block; }
```

I've two types of DIV, one is with single button and another is with two buttons.

Is it possible to always vertical align them, either single or two buttons?

Here's my link
http://codepen.io/w3nta1/pen/wGxOzO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLj7y4ev/) which can help you.

## HTML

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <div class="imageBox">
   <div class="imageActions">
   <a href="#"><div class="box">link1</div></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>

<li>
 <div class="imageBox">
  <div class="imageActions">
   <a href="#"><div class="box">link1</div></a>
   <a href="#"><div class="box">link2</div></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
ul { list-style: none; }
li { width : 200px; }
.imageBox {display: table;height:120px;width:120px}
.imageActions {display:table-cell;height:120px;vertical-align:middle}
.imageBox { with:196px; height:100px; position:relative; background:#000; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom:2px; }

.imageBox .box {  margin: 5px auto; padding: 5px; border:solid 1px #6f94e1; background-color:#456fd3; color:#FFF; width:100px; font-size:13px; text-align:center; } 


.imageBox .imageActions { width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); opacity: 0;}
.imageBox:hover .imageActions { opacity: 1; }
```

## UPDATED

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zLj7y4ev/2/) I have updated the height and width of `.imageBox`

Answer (score 0):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#9711efdfbb1bae01637fbd39d75ce11a

*This is an easy fix.*

Set `.imageBox` to have a `display: table;`
Then set `.imageActions` to have a `display: table-cell;`

Because `.imageActions` is displayed as a `table-cell` now you can use `vertical-align: middle;` to center your anchors vertically in the div.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
}

.imageBox {
  display: table;
  width: 196px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.imageBox .box {
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #6f94e1;
  background-color: #456fd3;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imageBox .imageActions {
  border-top-color: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}

.imageBox:hover .imageActions {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imageBox">
      <div class="imageActions">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="box">link1</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="imageBox">
      <div class="imageActions">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="box">link1</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="box">link2</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm on a tablet which is why I'm using [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#9711efdfbb1bae01637fbd39d75ce11a) and thus why I saved the weave utilizing [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) and [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) preprocessors.